# android load image from url use universal image loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use Universal image loader to load about 50 image from url
List image with some image have size 960px x 1378px and some image have size 1920px x 1378px 
this is my binder data

```
public class BinderDataImg extends BaseAdapter {
static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> imgHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;
public BinderDataImg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public BinderDataImg(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgHashmap.size();
}
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_img, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv_img =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImg);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }
    String uri = imgHashmap .get(position).get(KEY_IMG);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, holder.iv_img);
    return vi;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView iv_img;
}
```

}

this is config of Universal image loader in activity

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

all image loaded, but when scroll up or down , image in up or below reload again
and another problem
when screen is vertical, width of screen use size of image 960x1378
all image fill screen
but when rotate screen to horizontal , width of screen use size of image 1960x1378
and image 960x1378 will smaller
why that ? and how to fix it
sorry for my bad English
thank you for reading

Comment: its is happening because when you scroll up or down view gets refreshed, simply saying getView method of adapter is called again and again to refresh the view so image reloads. That's normal.

Comment: this is normal ? and if I rotate screen , image will smaller . this is normal too?

Comment: yeah that's normal man.
If your image is getting smaller that your layout problem, that's not normal.

Comment: yeah , i know, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I was update in my post

Answer (score 0):

The view of each row in `ListView` is reusable, therefore `getView()` method in your adapter need call multiple times when you scroll for fill correct data for row. It's normal behaviour of ListView adapter. Your `getView()` call then your image will reload.

To understand why `getView()` need to call I suggest that
 - You can create an int[] array for save the position where image have loaded
 - Then in `getView()` check the image is loaded or not
 - If it loaded then you don't load

I expect the result is after you scroll you ListView, all item of your ListView will be same

Hope this help

Comment: i have another problem , when rotate screen to horizontal , image will smaller , how to fix it

Comment: you should update your question with image,xml layout or post another question

Answer (score -1):

You are creating **new Instance** everytime in **getView()**:

Your updated code:

```
public class BinderDataImg extends BaseAdapter {
static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> imgHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public BinderDataImg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public BinderDataImg(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgHashmap.size();
}
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_img, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv_img =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImg);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }
    String uri = imgHashmap .get(position).get(KEY_IMG);
    imageLoader.displayImage(uri, holder.iv_img);
    return vi;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView iv_img;
}

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank for your help , but it still like this, nothing change

Comment: @abcd1234, have u tried imageLoader.displayImage(uri, holder.iv_img);

Comment: I follow you , but it still like that . and I have another problem , if I rotate screen , Image will smaller . why that ? can you fix it